# How to use a LaTeX template created in TeXstudio in overleaf?

Tags: packages, texstudio, overleaf, document-classes

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm using overleaf to ease collaboration with co-authors for a paper. I need to follow a template that was provided by the conference, and they say the template has been checked with TeXstudio. When I import the project, it does not compile and produces many errors like the following one:

```
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.71 \par
         
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

I think it may be related to the loading of packages. They are defined in a separate
`conference_paper.cls` file, using e.g. `\RequirePackage{paralist}`. And then when they start the `main.tex` file, they call the `class` they created: `\documentclass{conference_paper}`. I thought it was missing to include in the `main.tex` file something like `\usepackage{paralist}`, but this didn't work either. So I'm confused about how to use properly this template in overleaf.

Comment: probably you just need your `main.tex` and  `conference_paper.cls` packages like paralist are pre-installed in texlive/overleaf

Comment: The error you show is a syntax error in the tex not a missing file error.  Just look at the _first_ error, any later ones may be spurious

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the first error is actually "This compile didn’t produce a PDF. This can happen if: There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error.  If there are LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile again. The document environment contains no content. If it’s empty, please add some content and compile again. ". And the second error was the one I mentioned in the question. Can you share with me how to pre-installed packages in overleaf? From what I found in their website, It's not very clear for me how to do this.

Comment: no that is not from tex it is a heading added by overleaf just to say an error occurred. So it is actually _last_ after tex has finished. Look at the log file. You have not even shown the error message (which will start with `!`) you have just shown the 2nd half of the message with some context lines. messages do not start with `<inserted text> `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm sorry if I'm understanding wrong, but in the log file the first error I find after `!` is the same as in my question: `! Argument of Â has an extra }. <inserted text>    \par l.71 \par    I've run across a `} that doesn't seem to match anything.  ...`

Comment: so the actual error message (that you did not show until now) is `! Argument of Â has an extra }.`  The following part is just tex saying how it recovered. The message means your file is not correctly encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: make sure in texstudio you are _not_ using `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and the file is saved as UTF-8 it should then work better on overleaf.

Comment: I found the problem, thank you for your help! The template in textstudio is actually using `\RequirePackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`. But, it's also using the `hyperref` package. I found here: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/833 that there are compatibility issues. I tested and indeed by removing one or another the code compiles.

Comment: remove utf8x it does not do anything useful in modern latex